# Communicate with backend as safe as possible

Tags: android

I'm about to start the design of an application for Android (and possibly later on iPhone, if I ever get around learning it). In this application I will need to send and retrieve various information to a backend (that me myself also will need to design and code). The information will most likely be in json format.

How would I go about making this data as safely transmitted as possible? Is https the only anser to this? Or are there any other smart solutions to this?

Comment: "How would I go about making this data as safely transmitted as possible?" -- define "safely transmitted". Who you are trying to defend against? People attacking the Web site? ISPs? Governments? Users?

Comment: Oh, sorry, with safely transmitted I meant that if someone would get hold of the packages, they wouldn't be able to do anything with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS (including HTTPS), **where you validate the certificates from the client and the server** is the safest mechanism, and doesn't require you to reinvent authentication in some flawed way.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer and for guiding me in the right path. I was actually contemplating writing some sort of own authentication, that as you put it, most likely to be flawed. After some googling I've found some tips and guides to follow.